# React Native Acceptance Testing

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, acceptance-testing, atdd

I have an application with react-native and i need build a valid .ipa or .app for iOS to execute acceptance test with appium and node.

At the moment i use the `react-native run-ios --configuration Release` command but in the continuous integration machine opens a new terminal window with an express process in watch mode:
[image]

How i can close this process? Or any argument to not openit